# How to get a node's field and avg all of them in total?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

[My Schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Q1Lt.png)

**This is what I need my query to do:**
For classification "Sophomore", list the classification (Sophomore) and the average GPA of students with that classification.

**This is what I have:**

```
MATCH (user)<-[:Student]-(Student)
WHERE user.Classification = "Sophomore"
RETURN user.GPA as Student
```

Comment: The schema you posted does not match the schema of your actual graph, if that query is accurate. What is the result of `CALL db.schema;`?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your schema it appears that you have all relevant properties (Classification and GPA) on the Student node label. If that's the case there's no need to traverse a relationship here. Try this query:

```
MATCH (s:Student) WHERE s.Classification = "Sophomore"
RETURN avg(s.GPA)
```